# A way to call a command prompt function from controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cmd, controller

I'm trying to make a thumbnail in a Laravel project and I tried a lot other ways but with no success - Libraries, APIs... The problem is that the project is developed in Windows and the professor needs it in Windows as well.

So far, I experimented to integrate different libraries (wkhtmltoimage, spatie/browsershot, mpdf and s.o.) but in the most of the cases, there are problems with the path. 
The required function, which I need, works very good in command prompt and I thought that I must find a way to call it in the controller.

I've tried with:

```
shell_execute($call); 
system($call);
exec($call);

// with $call = "{func_name} {path_to_input_file} {name_of_output_file}";
// Example: $call = "wkhtmltoimage C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\test.html img.jpg"
```

But no result. The function generates an image, which I want to store in the database.

Is there an other way to make a call to the command prompt? 
Maybe SSH call?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `Artisan` commands directly via your controller.

Look at this example from the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands):

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);

    //
});
```

Comment: Yes, you're right but only `Artisan` commands, what about the other?